# Neutral $K$ and $B$ mesons decay to 2 photons?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics

The neutral pion $\pi^0$ decays almost exclusively to 2 photons, $\pi^0 \rightarrow \gamma \gamma$,

which got me thinking:

Can we have $K^0 \rightarrow \gamma \gamma$ and $B^0 \rightarrow \gamma \gamma$ or are they forbidden for some reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are both allowed, but they are flavor-changing neutral currents that are loop-supressed. The $B^0\to\gamma\gamma$ decay occurs by the Feynman diagrams from [arXiv:1010.2229](http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.2229) and I imagine that kaon decay proceeds similarly.

[image: Feynman diagram]

They are so suppressed that the $B^0$ decay hasn't been measured, but [PDG](http://pdg8.lbl.gov/rpp2014v1/pdgLive/BranchingRatio.action?parCode=S042&desig=141) report an  upper bound on the branching ratio of $<3.2\times 10^{−7}$. The kaon decay has been [measured](http://pdg8.lbl.gov/rpp2014v1/pdgLive/BranchingRatio.action?parCode=S013&desig=9) as long ago as the 60s, remarkably. The branching ratios are much less than that of the pion, but, then again, the $\pi\to\gamma\gamma$ decay proceeds through the [axial anomaly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiral_anomaly), so it's not surprising that it's atypical.

Comment: Thanks. Out of curiosity, do both diagrams have the same order?
How many loops are there in the second?